# How to represent and work with the feature matrix for graph convolutional network (GCN) if the number of features for each node is different?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn

I have a question regarding features representation for graph convolutional neural network.

For my case, all nodes have a different number of features, and for now, I don't really understand how should I work with these constraints. I can not just reduce the number of features or add meaningless features in order to make the number of features on each node the same - because it will add to much extra noise to the network.

Are there any ways to solve this problem? How should I construct the feature matrix?

I'll appreciate any help and if you have any links to papers that solve this problem.